# Why does this sentence eliminate the "unreferenced function argument warning"?

Tags: c, warnings, compiler-warnings, sdcc

in SDCC Compiler User Guide I read the following:

```
void to_buffer( unsigned char c )
{
c; // to avoid warning: unreferenced function argument
__asm
; save used registers here.
; If we were still using r2,r3 we would have to push them here.
; if( head != (unsigned char)(tail-1) )
mov a,_tail
dec a
xrl a,_head
; we could do an ANL a,#0x0f here to use a smaller buffer (see below)
jz t_b_end$
;
; buf[ head++ ] = c;
mov a,dpl ; dpl holds lower byte of function argument
mov dpl,_head ; buf is 0x100 byte aligned so head can be used directly
mov dph,#(_buf>>8)
movx @dptr,a
inc _head
; we could do an ANL _head,#0x0f here to use a smaller buffer (see above)
t_b_end$:
; restore used registers here
__endasm;
}
```

I don't understand what does the sentence `"c; // to avoid warning: unreferenced function argument"` mean, is it a special usage of SDCC? Or a special usage of C language?

Comment: Did you search for the warning message in the comment? What in the expalanation did you not understand? (Btw, it should be `(void)c;`, otherwise other compilers like gcc might complain with "result of expression not used" or similar.) Addition: the very first search result points to the sdcc support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilers tend to warn you if you have an incoming function parameter that you don't use. In your case, `c;` is a *void* operation to access the variable and to avoid the warning. It is similar to

```
 int func(char c)
 {
  (void)c;
  //c is never used in the function
 }
```

FWIW, in `gcc`, to *enable* the warning, `-Wunused-parameter` option is used. (*enabled in `-Wextra`*)

Comment: Thanks. And is it a special usage of SDCC? Can this be used in other compliers?

Comment: @Qiang This is no _special_ usage, just a workaround for a clean compilation. However, it's always better to change the code to get rid of the warnings rather than suppressing them. :)